# Why doesn't SQLite JOIN work?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I've a problem with the following function. Its just the join I think. By using sql statement "SELECT * FROM pkw", I got the results. Both tables are filled with data.
Do you see the mistake?

```
function gotoauftrag(id) {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
    var list = '';
    var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM pkw p INNER JOIN ta_pkw tp ON tp.pkw_id = p.pkw_id AND tp.ta_id = ?";
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                   tx.executeSql(sql, [id], function (tx, results) {
                                 if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                                 document.getElementById('auftrag_pkw').innerHTML = '';
                                 for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                                    r = results.rows.item(i);
                                    list = '<li>'+r['name']+'<span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>';
                                 document.getElementById('auftrag_pkw').innerHTML += list;
                                 $('#auftrag_pkw').listview('refresh');
                                 }
                                 }
                                 });
                   });
$('#auftrag_pkw').listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Does it work without the join or without the `ta_id` filter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are able to bind to the `JOIN` predicate.  Try using the `WHERE` clause instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  p.name 
FROM pkw p 
INNER JOIN ta_pkw tp 
  ON tp.pkw_id = p.pkw_id 
WHERE
  tp.ta_id = ?
```

Also, you probably should be doing the `ta_id` selection before your join.  The above will do a natural join on `pkw_id`, THEN it will filter the results based on `ta_id`.